# Спрятать вертикальную границу ячейки таблицы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как в таблице бутстрап (у меня v3.3.7) убрать одну из вертикальных границ ячейки?

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Блабла</td>
            <td>Примечание</td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Блабла</td>
            <td>Блабла2</td>
            <td style="border-right:0;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Хочется добиться такого эффекта:

[image: Желаемый результат]

У меня получилось только через `style="border-right-color: white;"` – но ведь это не совсем правильный хак (для тёмной схемы сайта уже не сработает).

Гуглил... Нашёл пару вопросов, но толи недопонял, как сделать, толи не то:

- [How do I hide a cell border in a Bootstrap 4 table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43918421/5752652)
- [Bootstrap table-bordered remove right, left borders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20821662/5752652)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы у первой ячейки убираете границу  `style="border-right:0;"`, но у правой она остается. Т.е. если решили убирать таким способом - второй ячейке добавьте `style="border-left:0;"`

Переделанный код:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Блабла</td>
            <td>Примечание</td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Блабла</td>
            <td>Блабла2</td>
            <td style="border-right:0;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
            <td style="border-left:0;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Да, способ рабочий. Надо же, не подумал, что нужно у обоих ячеек убирать. Как всё просто...

Answer (score 1):

Обязательно нужны две ячейки? как по мне лучшим выходом будет разместить все то, что вы хотели разместить в двух ячейках, разместить в одной. Тем боле на скриншоте скорее всего так.

Comment: Я не дизайнер и не верстальщик, так что у меня в одной ячейке как-то некрасиво выходит. А так - да, можно в принципе и в одной попробовать сделать. Но кода вы (пока?) не привели - так что пока это скорее не ответ, а комментарий к вопросу.